# Are there any Candy Box bugs higher than level 5?

Tags: candy-box

In Candy Box, the developper’s console lets you create bugs. It shows different buttons for different level bugs depending on how many lollipops you have. If you have 100 billion or more, it says that there are no level-six bugs, but “maybe level 7”. If you have 1 trillion or more, it says there are no level-seven bugs either, but “don’t give up”.

However it doesn’t change no matter how many more lollipops you have. You can add 10e200 and it remains the same.

Is there something more to see or is that goading text just a ruse or prank to hassle (obsessive) players and trick them into wasting some time.

---

[image: Screenshot of developper’s computer with “don’t give up” message]

Comment: Just a bit curious, when you changed your lollipops to 10e999, did it say you had 10e999 lollipops? I was  trying to see how high I could get my candies up and somewhere around 10e300 (probably less) candies it said I had infinity candies. Eating them gave me infinite health. Just curious has to whether explicitly inputting 10e999 would bypass this effect.

Comment: nvm,  Number.MAX_VALUE = 1.7976931348623157e+308, any number beyond that would be displayed as infinite.

Comment: I was being hyperbolic. I don’t remember the exact number I used, but it was extremely high, and yet nothing changed (there was no level-eight line added below the level-seven line), which is what prompted me to ask.

Comment: Strange that someone felt the need to downvote the question and all answer without bothering to leave an explanation. ◔_◔

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked the page’s source (below) which shows that the bugs are hidden and displayed dynamically. The randomize bugs appear after you reach 10 trillion lollipops, the randomize buttons become available, and while it doesn’t say so, the source considers that as being “level-eight” as per the `computer_bug_8` ID of the *Bug Factory* section.

---

[image: Screenshot of Candy Box source with bug section higlighted]

Comment: Personally, I can appreciate the prank. In one of my old programs, I added an easter-egg that changed the title of the about-box to a “cutsey” depending on how many times you clicked the program icon. I added a dozen or so and made it so that pretty much everybody would give up before the last couple of levels which required so many clicks that your finger would fall off (assuming you physically performed it). Naturally, these sorts of things *have* to have an end at some point since there’s no way to make unique, non-random things last indefinitely.

Comment: It is not a prank. By gaining a sufficient number of lollipops beyond the million of millions of lollipops needed for the non-existent level 7 bug, you unlock the "bug factory" where you can randomize candies and lollipops among other things like adding additional (though useless) tabs and changing font size and background colour of the game.

Comment: Yes, I added that.

Comment: @hit-and-run-down-voter, I found a definitive answer by directly examining the code. So what’s your problem?

Answer (score 4):

Ahh here we go... (Spoilers ahead)

**Guide to achieving higher level bugs**

The level two bug typically has you encounter people who give you millions of candies (or you just pick up the candies you tossed on the floor earlier). Start here and accumulate a few 100 million candies.

The level three bug has multiple consequences:

- Increase Sword level by 1
- Decrease Sword level by 3
- Times 3 candies
- Absolutely nothing (as in the image in the picture)

Exploit the level three bugs to multiple you candies to an absurd amount. (over 10 trillion) (if you run out of lollipops, proceed to next step to get more).

Let the candy to lollipop converter run for some time (15 to 20 minutes should do) and all you candies will become lollipops. At this point you will unlock all the bugs and your game will look like this (give you have over 10 trillion lollipops):
[image: Candy Box Bugs]

**Some additional notes:**

Level 5 bug can:

- unlock a secret pony mode that turns all your opponents into ponies
- Sword of Randomness (combines all 3 swords into one)
- Bug with the Bug, absolutely nothing happens.

Level 1 bug:

- Receive 1 to 3 bars of chocolate
- Absolutely nothing

The point is that the bugs aren't unique and after purchasing a bug once it is still worthwhile to do it again. One of the bugs increases you maximum lollipop production (planting more lollipops will increase your product up to 30000 a second I believe, still rather pointless at this point).

Comment: Again, this isn’t helpful, I have already tried manually changing the number of lollipops to gigantic numbers (I even tried setting it to 10e999). Nothing worked. Have you *personally seen* level eight or higher bugs?

Comment: @synetech see picture

Comment: Your screenshot shows only up to level-five bugs and the level-six and seven messages I already showed in the question. Did you even read the question?

Comment: @Synetech It clearly says "Welcome to the bug factory! You now have access to the entire computer, and you can therefore create your own bugs."

Comment: That is referring to the buttons below that randomize things. That has nothing to do with the level bugs above that message.

Comment: Those buttons are the level 8 bug.... you unlock them by gaining a large number of lollipops beyond the amount needed for level 7 bug. The message that appears "don't give up" is in reference to the bug factory.

Comment: Yes, I saw that. However it doesn’t actually say that which makes it not obvious that it is part of the levels (the factory just seems like a new, *different* thing that opened while the bug section remains unchanged with the *don’t give up* message lingering there).

Comment: It depends on how you got there I suppose. Users who don't use their browser's console to edit their lollipop count see the bug factory appears sequentially long after the level 7 but while they are attempting to find the threshold for the level 8 bug. When it appears, it is clear from that standpoint that they achieved something (I still don't know where exactly that threshold is, the first time around after going up several orders of lollipops and not seeing anything, I went for an absurd number of lollipops and got this).

Comment: The bug factory becomes accessible with 10 trillion lollipops. Also, it’s not obvious because by that point, you might cross that threshold while in one of the other tabs (or not even playing the game and it reaches 10Tlp while you’re off doing something else), so you might notice the bug factory when you happen to view the computer tab later on. Plus, there is the divide in the layout, but now we’re getting into UI design. `:-)`

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a Level 8 bug. Unlocked at 10,000,000 mlp, It gives access to the "bug factory" in which you can randomize various aspects of the game. You need a base of 10,000,000 mlp, but activating any of these bugs does not cost lollipops. There are no bugs beyond level 8, though.

Comment: But how do you get it? I tried adding 10e200 lollipops but nothing came up.

Comment: I haven't edited the game using my browser, but I was able to get trillions of trillions of lollipops by manipulating the above bugs. The bugs aren't necessarily unique and may have other affects if you try to use them again. It's been a while since I played by there should be a bug that substantially multiplies your candies. After you get some absurd amount of candies, the candy to lollipop converter can convert them all given that you let it run for a while (at a certain point it converts all regardless of how many). At that point the higher level bugs.

Comment: @Nil, at what point do you see level-eight? I already tried manually setting the number of lollipops. That’s how I was able to see the level-five, six, and seven messages. I tried setting it to 10e200 but still did not see a level-eight.

Comment: Adding in a little bit more detail would be most useful.  Just saying what's possible, while technically answering the question, isn't very useful.

Comment: I didn't want to give spoilers, but if you insist.